# how to call different servlet on clicking different button of html form

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

i have a html form i want to call two different servlet on clicking two different button how to change the form action run time

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Question Paper" style="height:25px; width:120px; background-color: royalblue;color: white;" />
<input type="submit" value="Instruction" style="height:25px; width:120px; background-color: royalblue;color: white;" />");
 </form>
```

on clicking the button i want to call servlet1 and servlet2 on each button

please help me to solve this problem, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this.

Probably the easiest would be to use JavaScript to change the form's action.

```
<input type="submit" value="SecondServlet" onclick="form.action='SecondServlet';">
```

But this of course won't work when the enduser has JS disabled (mobile browsers, screenreaders, etc).

Another way is to put the second button in a different form, which may or may not be what you need, depending on the concrete functional requirement, which is not clear from the question at all.

```
<form action="FirstServlet" method="Post">
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="FirstServlet">
</form>
<form action="SecondServlet" method="Post">
    <input type="submit"value="SecondServlet">
</form>
```

Note that a form would on submit only send the input data contained in the very same form, not in the other form.

Again another way is to just create another single entry point servlet which delegates further to the right servlets (or preferably, the right business actions) depending on the button pressed (which is by itself available as a request parameter by its name):

```
<form action="MainServlet" method="Post">
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="FirstServlet">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="SecondServlet">
</form>
```

with the following in `MainServlet`

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");

if ("FirstServlet".equals(action)) {
    // Invoke FirstServlet's job here.
} else if ("SecondServlet".equals(action)) {
    // Invoke SecondServlet's job here.
}
```